# iOS App background processes run perfectly on device but only when is plugged into Xcode.

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an app that uses location services in the background running iOS7... When its plugged into xcode and it goes into the background I can see all the processes running and the app staying in a suspended state... However when I unplug from the computer and try to run on device the app seems to terminate and relaunch to the origin screen (as if being terminated)... Why is this happening?

Comment: Are two test scenarios on the same device?

Comment: What do you mean by that? I basically have one method for beginBackgroundTask that sets a timer to go. The timer fires the gps to start every x minutes to keep the app alive and to report the gps location to a server... In xcode it reports its sending gps updates and all is fine however when not in xcode no gps updates are received by the server...

Comment: iOS 7 provides user ability to switch off apps running in background through "Settings" app > General > "Background App Refresh". Refer to this link for more advanced discussion - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19235183/uiapplicationbackgroundrefreshstatusdidchangenotification-usage-without-correspo

Comment: Yeah background app refresh is enabled for this app already :(