# Background App Refresh checking, enabling and disabling programmatically for whole device and for each particular application in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, appsettings

We can check Background App Refresh for whole device and for each particular application in iOS 7 manually from settings.

[image]

Is there any way to do it programmatically in iOS 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is no you can't check to see what every app's Background Refresh setting is due to application sandboxing.  An application may how ever check to see if the user has modified the Background Refresh setting for itself.

[Detecting user settings for Background App Refresh in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520787/detecting-user-settings-for-background-app-refresh-in-ios-7)

Comment: Trevor, is there any restriction from Apple explaining this or any other source to validate this your answer?