# ios background fetch app settings - read from info.plist in code

Tags: ios, swift, background, background-fetch

In my iOS App I've enable the Backgrdound Fetch capability available since iOS 7 (Project > Capablities > Background Modes > Background Fetch).

Initially, I defined a boolean setting (I called it "*Enable Background Fetch*") in `Root.plist` allowing the app to enable/disable this functionality but, after recompiling and executing, I've noticed that in the app settings screen, a boolean setting named "*Background App Refresh*" is already added automatically on top of my other custom settings.

My question is: can I access the value of this automatically added property, and not have to define my own duplicate setting key? I need to read the value of the property from my app code, since other aspects of my app's behaviour depend on whether background fetches are enabled or not.

Can I invoke `NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey(...)` and in this case which value for the key should I use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting user settings for Background App Refresh in iOS 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18520787/detecting-user-settings-for-background-app-refresh-in-ios-7)

Comment: I tried to test the solution in the thread you pointed to, but it didn't solve my problem: I always got the "_Background updates are available for the app._" message regardless the setting of the "_Background App Refresh_" switch. Actually, thogugh, I noticed a strange thing: the boolean setting is always reset to "true" (I go to Settings > My App > set the "Background App Refresh" to "false", press the back button, then go again to My App settings and find that it is again set to "true")!